# Problems having popup modal dialog to show on top of content

Tags: css, modal-dialog, popup, z-index

I am having problems getting the popup box to display on top of the content. I have tried applying high z-index values to the containers but it doesn't help. Any ideas?
You can check the example [here](https://sgp8.siteground.asia/~uniqtone/hccr/test/)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

```
   .wpb_column grve-column grve-bookmark grve-column-1-2 {
    z-index:0;
    }
    .grve-element grve-text {
    z-index:0;
    }
    .pop-up-box {
    z-index:0;
    } 

Add This Css Its Working.
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but doesn't work =( You can check the example link

Comment: Remove Z-index below class From Grid.css
======
.grve-column-1-12, .grve-column-5-12, .grve-column-7-12, .grve-column-11-12, .grve-column-1-6, .grve-column-1-5, .grve-column-1-4, .grve-column-1-2, .grve-column-1-3, .grve-column-2-3, .grve-column-3-4, .grve-column-4-5, .grve-column-5-6, .grve-column-1
=======

Remove z-index from grid.css
====
.grve-element


also remove z-index from all class which i tell you before

Comment: thanks, it's better now but still the popup boxes gets hidden behind the bottom text row. (see the example link)